# Why is my categories template in wordpress returning posts not in the category in question?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having an issue with my Category template. With a number of categories it's echoing posts that aren't in the category in question. I've checked the posts and categories in my WPAdmin dashboard, they're correct; the problem lies with my code.

Side note: this loop always returns every post in the category, and then some. So it's not *missing* any, it's just including some that don't belong.

```
<?php
$categories = get_the_category(); $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'cat' => $category_id )); ?>
    <?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() and !empty($category_id) ) : ?>
    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div>
      <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <p><br/><?php echo get_the_date('l, F j, Y'); _e(' by ');?><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo the_author_meta('nicename'); ?>"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></p>
      <p><br/><?php _e('Categories: '); echo the_category( '/' ); ?></p>
      <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
      <span><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 55 ) ); ?><br/><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">Continue Reading ></a></span>
      <p><br/><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      <p><?php echo get_the_date('l, F j, Y'); _e(' by ');?><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo the_author_meta('nicename'); ?>"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></p>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->
<?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php else : ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: AFAIK get_the_category needs the post id when used outside the loop, so I am guessing you are getting a 'sort of' undefined result, ie anything goes. Try something daft like  get_the_category($post->ID) and see if it improves matters. Otherwise  try your loop with a hard coded cat id and see if you still get wierd results.

Comment: I changed   $categories = get_the_category(); $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;    to      $categories = get_the_category($post->ID); $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;    and that didn't work. I hardcoded the cat id, and it worked right. But obviously that won't do. Thanks though!

Comment: I appreciate it won't do, but is shows where the problem is. You are not getting your cat_id, so need to sort out that first line of code.

Comment: Back in the office and troubleshooting. I had it return the category id to console, and I noted that all of the ids 7 and below are coming back correctly, all of the ids 8 are coming back incorrectly, bit much to call that a coincidence. Will update when I have a solution.

Comment: There, got it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I have the solution. I was getting the post outside the loop, so it was defaulting to the first post. Most posts on this blog have multiple categories, and the ordering wasn't always listing the desired category first. This solution guarantees the category is grabbed based on the page loaded, rather than just the first category of the post:

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
preg_match('/\/category\/(.+)\/.*/', $url, $matches);
$category_slug = $matches[1];
$category_id_actual = get_category_by_slug($category_slug)->term_id;
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'cat' => $category_id_actual )); ?>
<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() and !empty($category_id_actual) ) : ?>
  <!-- the loop -->
  <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
      <div>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><br/><?php echo get_the_date('l, F j, Y'); _e(' by ');?><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo the_author_meta('nicename'); ?>"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></p>
        <p><br/><?php _e('Categories: '); echo the_category( '/' ); ?></p>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
        <span><?php echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_trim_words( strip_tags( $post->post_content ), 55 ) ); ?><br/><a href="<?php echo the_permalink();?>">Continue Reading ></a></span>
        <p><br/><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <p><?php echo get_the_date('l, F j, Y'); _e(' by ');?><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/author/<?php echo the_author_meta('nicename'); ?>" class="authorname"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></p>
        <div style="float:right;"></div>
      </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <!-- end of the loop -->
  <?php wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```